# Ubuntu: Graphics Driver Problem (Intel)

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

Hello Everyone I am having an issue with Ubuntu Graphics Driver whenever I try to open my pc after booting ubuntu my monitor gets a blank screen, I don't know why this is happening.

For Booting my Ubuntu successfully I have to go to the advanced option from the boot menu and then run ubuntu from there. I think it is a graphics driver problem as after booting ubuntu from advanced settings I get a message saying that the graphics driver will not boot for booting them restart the pc and run ubuntu normally.

**My PC Specs**

Monitor with VGA directly form the mother board

Integrated graphics of **Intel Core i3 10100**

Mother board **MSI M410 M-HV3**

---

I have some pictures I am attaching the pictures here:

[image: Selecting Advance Option From Boot Menu]

[image: Selecting Next Option]

[image: Booting it normally]

[image: Driver Warning]

Answer (score 1):

The Intel graphics driver is part of the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver package, which is installed on all Ubuntu systems by default. And since it isn't a proprietary driver package, it doesn't show up in jockey (aka the Hardware Drivers application).

Just to ensure it didn't get removed by mistake (very slim possibility), just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

If the driver is installed, and you're still having issues with graphics on your desktop, then please file a bug report against the xorg package, using this terminal command:

```
apport-bug xorg
```